# Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Tags: rna-seq, bioconductor, rstudio

I tried to run the following code in R studio. Everything worked fine, except at the last step [write.table(mdat, "recount_mdat.csv")] when I tried to export the 'mdat', I got the following error:

```
Error in as.vector(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

My code:

```
 library('dplyr')
 library('recount')
 library('magrittr')
 library('ffpe')
 library('RSkittleBrewer')
 library('SummarizedExperiment')
 library('devtools')
 trop <- RSkittleBrewer::RSkittleBrewer('tropical')
 colon_proj <- c('SRP025982', 'SRP42161')
 if(any(!file.exists(file.path(colon_proj, 'rse_gene.Rdata')))) {
 sapply(colon_proj, download_study)
 }

 blood_proj <- c('SRP066834', 'SRP041736', 'SRP060416')
 if(any(!file.exists(file.path(blood_proj, 'rse_gene.Rdata')))) {
 sapply(blood_proj, download_study)
 }
 proj <- c(colon_proj,blood_proj)

 dat <- lapply(proj, function(x) {
 load(file.path(x, 'rse_gene.Rdata'))
 return(rse_gene)
 })
 proj

 sapply(dat, dim)

 metadata <- all_metadata('sra')

 write.table(metadata, "recount_metadata.csv")

 mdat <- do.call(cbind, dat)

 write.table(mdat, "recount_mdat.csv")

is(mdat)
## "RangedSummarizedExperiment" "SummarizedExperiment" "Vector" "Annotated"
```

Comment: What is the class of mdat? Did you try `is(mdat)`? What did you get?

Comment: @IIrs Hi I got this after this step

               [1] "RangedSummarizedExperiment" "SummarizedExperiment"       
               "Vector"                    
       [4] "Annotated"

Comment: Great, see how fast you got your answer when you provided enough details, remember to include all the relevant details next time! Glad you found how to solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cbind a bunch of obscure object types.

If you want merged count tables you should do this:

```
mdat <- do.call(cbind,lapply(dat,assay))
```

Where **row.names** are *Ensembl gene IDs* and **col.names** are the *SRR accessions*.

Then run your table writing command.

-

If you want the coordinates of your genes then do this to make a bed with the genomic locations:

```
library(rtracklayer)
export.bed(rowRanges(dat[[1]]),'gene_coords.bed')
```